# Android ExpandedListView animation to expand slow and smooth

Tags: android, expandablelistview

When the ordinary ExpandableListView expands we usually see just the result that it is expanded. I want to add animation to see clearly that it expands itself a little bit slowly and smooth in order to clerify for user that he clicked on listitem and it opened.

Answer (score 1):

- this can be achieve by Accordion component  .
  have a look on to this [link](http://android-puremvc-ormlite.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-simple-accordion-panel.html)

May be it will helpfull to you.
Thanks

Comment: I dont know. He uses ListActivity, not ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like the accordion, but only want to have one item expanded at once, and you want to keep using your normal ListView, I would recommend this project: https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

Yes I am the Author!